# Amazon EC2: PHPMyAdmin Error: The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I know that many people has asked this question, But I believe that its all old answers, nothing worked here ..

When I've installed PhPMyadmin 4.7.0 I got this message:

The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

I tried to search on all answers, but nothing changed:

Some people asked to fix some issues in this file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

But I dont have this file at all!

Some people said that this line can fix: yum install php56-mbstring

but its not fixed.

My php-v said:

PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 19:08:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

now what to do? How I can fix it

Comment: how did you try to fix it?

Comment: In this page: [link] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

Instead if this command: 'sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd'


I used this one: 'sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php-56-mysqlnd'

Then follow all steps in this link: [link] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

In this page: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.ht‌​ml

Instead of using this command: sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd

I used this one:

sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php-56-mysqlnd

Then follow all steps in this link:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.ht‌​ml